# How to provide more than one input file argument for Nco.ncrcat()

Tags: netcdf, nco

I want to call the NCO command ncrcat via the Python NCO bindings. From what I can tell there is only the ability to specify a single input file argument, and my ncrcat command requires two.

The command I'm trying to replicate in my Python code:

```
$ ncrcat -O -L 4 input_1.nc input_2.nc output
```

Maybe I include an iterable in the place of the single input, like so:

```
from nco import Nco
nco = Nco()
nco.ncrcat(input=[input_1,input_2],
           output=output_netcdf,
           options=['-O', '-4', '-L 4', '-h'])
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep thats the right syntax for specifying more than one input file
   ...Henry